# Flask: cannot import name 'app'

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Trying to run my python file `updater.py` to SSH to a server and run some commands every few set intervals or so. I'm using APScheduler to run the function `update_printer()` from `__init__.py`. Initially I got a `working outside of application context error` but someone suggested that I just import app from `__init__`.py. However it isn't working out so well. I keep getting a `cannot import name 'app'` error.

**app.py**

```
from queue_app import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from queue_app.updater import update_printer
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')

@app.before_first_request
def init():
    sched = BackgroundScheduler()
    sched.start()
    sched.add_job(update_printer, 'interval', seconds=10)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

**updater.py**

```
import paramiko
import json
from queue_app import app

def update_printer():
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(app.config['SSH_SERVER'], username = app.config['SSH_USERNAME'], password = app.config['SSH_PASSWORD'])

...
```

**File Structure**

```
queue/
   app.py
   config.py
   queue_app/
      __init__.py
      updater.py
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from queue_app import app
  File "/Users/name/queue/queue_app/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from queue_app.updater import update_printer
  File "/Users/name/queue/queue_app/updater.py", line 3, in <module>
    from queue_app import app
ImportError: cannot import name 'app'
```

What do I need to do be able to get to the app.config from updater.py and avoid a "working outside of application context error" if ran from APScheduler?

Comment: You might try a relative import in updater.py (e.g from . import app)

Comment: Same error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from queue_app import app
  File "/Users/name/queue/queue_app/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from queue_app.updater import update_printer
  File "/Users/name/queue/queue_app/updater.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import app
ImportError: cannot import name 'app'
`

Comment: Oh..you have a circular reference...app.py->__init__.py->updater.py->__init__.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a circular dependency, as you import `updater` in your `__init__.py` file. In my Flask setup, `app` is created in `app.py`.