# Flask ImportError: cannot import name 'app'

Tags: python, flask

I am new to flask and trying to learn blueprints but I am having trouble. My file structure is like this:

```
documents\flask(directory of my flask projects)
               \blueprint(my current project)
                    \site(where the modules sits)
                         \api
                             __init__.py
                             routes.py
                         \site
                             __init.py
                             routes.py 
                    __init__.py
               run.py
```

site/routes.py

```
from flask import Blueprint

mod_site = Blueprint('site', __name__)

@mod_site.route('/')
def main():
    return '<h1>You are on the homepage!</h1>'
```

api/routes.py

```
from flask import Blueprint

mod_api = Blueprint('api', __name__)

@mod_api.route('/getdata')
def getData():
    return '{"result":"You are in the API!"}'
```

site(main folder)/**init**.py

```
from flask import flask

app = Flask(__name__)

from site.api.routes import mod_api as api_module
from site.site.routes import mod_site as site_module

app.register_blueprint(site_module)
app.register_blueprint(api_module, url_prefix='/api')
```

run.py

```
from site import app

app.run(debug=True)
```

I get this error when I run it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "run.py", line 1, in <module>
   from site import app 
ImportError: cannot import name 'app'
```

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/a/35930393/2178980, as @Janukasamaranyake suggests? Have you Googled "cannot import name 'app'"? There are two more extremely similar SO questions. I'm assuming you've done this already?

Comment: Is `run.py` inside `flask` or `blueprint`? If the former, you'll need to add `site` to your `PYTHONPATH`.